# Simple RewriteRule doesn't change URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The thing I ask for is truly simple. I want to get from this:

```
http://test.com/index.php?articles=mynewarticle&id=5
```

to this:

```
http://test.com/mynewarticle.html
```

and I don't understand why, but the following .htaccess is not doing the job:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?articles=$1&id=5 [L]
```

When I type in

```
http://test.com/index.php?articles=mynewarticle&id=5
```

I get

```
http://test.com/index.php?articles=mynewarticle&id=5
```

Not sure if something is modified in Apache in the way that disables this option for me and I don't know where to check this. Thanks in advance for any of the help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a combination of external and internal RewriteRules to convert orignal url into SEO friendly format

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirect "/index.php?articles=foobar&id=123" to "/foobar.html"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?articles=([^&]+)&id=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [NE,L,R]
#rewrite "/foobar.html" to "/index.php?articles=foobar&id=5
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?articles=$1&id=5 [L]
```